# the Dot Character got encode when encoding a URL by coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam

Hi um using this piece of code to encode a url by coldfusion

```
dataURL=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#URLEncodedFormat(form.FLV_FILE_7,'UTF-8')#" maxlength="255">,
```

and it encode the dot character as well and this results a different  url when generating a signature for a particular url name  .  Any one has any idea about this issue? Is there a way to omit the dot character and do the urlEncode?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal as the docs mention URLEncodedFormat replaces all non-alphanumeric characters with equivalent hexadecimal escape sequences.

if you wish to not convert the dots, you could selectively revert them by wrapping it again with a #Replace(URLEncodedFormat(form.FLV_FILE_7,'UTF-8'),'%2E','.','ALL')#

although I would probably look at adjusting the parameters that are requiring you to keep the dots decoded which you don't mention and resolve it there if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could also call it as URLEncodedFormat(form['FLV_FILE_7'], 'UTF-8') and avoid the dot all together.